# how to get profile images with facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get **all** of the user profile images,

Mean I need more then the user profile image

I tried to get album, and to extract the images form it, but without success

Answer (score 1):

You need

- Valid access_token
- user_photos permissions

After that, get [photos](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)

Comment: yes but how can I now if the photo is one of the profile images?

Comment: @user954659: this will take every photo, including profile images

Comment: but how can I know if the image is one of the profile images?

Comment: @user954659: https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?access_token=access_token_here -> id of "Profile Pictures"

Comment: are you sure this call will not return the albums ids? and not the profile images?

Comment: I tried it but it didn't gave my a link to the profile images

Comment: @Ronaldinio: it will give you id of album -> then get it with /me/album/

Comment: @genesis this does not answer the question. OP is asking for *only* the profile images (and not just the default one).

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a [FQL query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/):

```
select pid, src, link, caption
from photo
where aid in 
  (SELECT aid 
   FROM album 
   WHERE owner=me() 
   and name="Profile Pictures")
```

This would require `user_photos` extended permission.